# Rebbe maamer modifying Tanya on non-Jew's soul root?

Tags: gentiles, soul, chassidic-rebbe, tanya

I heard from a friend that the Rebbe gave a maamer somewhat modifying the statement in Tanya  that all non-Jews' souls are from the klippot. Can anyone provide the exact source for it?

Comment: https://youtu.be/yIZihqVzR0o?t=27m5s No time to listen, but he brings all the sources there.

Comment: Which rebbe do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Siddur Im D'ach, Shaar Chag HaMatzot; Lekutei Biurim (By Rabbi Hillel Malisov of Paritch), 47b.

The Chassidei Umot haOlam derive their animal souls not from the 3 impure klipot, but from the klipat nogah, just like the animal soul of bnei Yisrael. The sheva mitzvot seem to be a rectification for the animal soul. Bnei Yisrael are born automatically with the animal soul from klipat nogah. The non-Jew may or may not and usually has to merit it on his own.

I don't believe this is a modification, but rather it gives a deeper understanding and purifies the vulgar common understanding.

Answer (score 1):

[Iggerot Kodesh, vol. 1, p. 176](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15875&st=&pgnum=209&hilite=):

בקיצור תניא להצ"צ... פ"ו כתב וז"ל: ג' קליפות הטומאה ואין בהם טוב כלל (ר"ל בעצמותם אבל בבחי' גלות בו יש חיות אלקות ניצוץ מי"ס דעשייה שבתוכו י"ס דיצירה שבתוכו וכו'). וביתר ביאור כתב ... וז"ל: מה שכתב בספר של בינונים דגקה"ט אין בהם טוב כלל, אין הכוונה שאין בהם שום ניצוץ כלל, שהרי אי אפשר להיות קיום שום דבר בלי איזה ניצוץ טוב... רק שהניצוץ הוא שנתרחק ונחשך כל כך עד שהוא כמו רע וכו'.

Comment: This doesn't mean what you seem to think it means.

Comment: @Yishai what do I think that it means?

Comment: see Tanya, Igeres HaKodesh 25. That is the concept this is referring to.

Comment: @Yishai Care to elaborate?

Comment: I'm not sure what isn't clear. It doesn't in any way "ameliorate" anything about Klippos beyond the standard understanding of Klippos in Chassidus.

Comment: @Yishai The Rebbe seemed to think that he was saying something beyond what was obvious in this letter. See esp. the paragraph beginning והנה אם בסברא. He also cites the Iggeres ha-Kodesh passage you mentioned at the end of the letter

Comment: Yeah, but that whole paragraph gets discarded in the next paragraph, which you quote from in your answer. To reword what that paragraph says - the holiness of the Mitzvos have no positive effect on their perception or understanding of G-dliness. The fact that they have a portion in the world to come is a function of the world to come, where Klipos will be purified. I doubt that is the entirety of the subject matter in Chassidus (especially given the date of the letter) but that is what this letter says.

Answer (score 0):

See Sichos Kodesh Shabbos Pinchos year 5741 section 6 based on R. Hillel Paritcher in the name of the Baal HaTanya & the Mitteler Rebbe clarifying the statement in Tanya end of chapter one.

I’ll paraphrase part of the Rebbe’s words: “in reference to the souls of the nations Sefer HaTanya speaks of the idol worshiping majority who’s souls come from the 3 impure husks, however the souls of the righteous amongst the nations who keep the 7 Noahide Laws come from the good of the 4th shining husk and therefore have a place in the World to Come”.

(Nevertheless, the Rebbe does say there that although both the נפש of חסידי אומות העולם  and a Jew’s נפש הבהמית come from קליפת נוגה, even a Jew’s נפש הבהמית is בעין ערוך to that of חסידי אומות העולם).

See Siddur Im Dach. Shaar Chag Hamatzot 287c; Likkutei Biurim (by Rabbi Hillel of Paritch) 47b quoted in Lessons in Tanya end of chapter 1.

See ChabadPedia for an in-depth article.
[http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/אומות_העולם](http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D)