# The metaphysical essence of the non-jewish person

Tags: sources-mekorot, gentiles, mysticism-kabbalah, soul, tanya

In the first chapter of the Tanya, the Alter Rebbe says that the *Nefesh Behemit*of a Jew comes from the *Klipat Noga* while the *Nefesh Behemit* of a Non-Jew comes from the unclean *Klipot* which contain no good at all. In the second chapter we learn that Jews have a g-dly soul which is a Part of G-d (and actually the Jews essence) but there is no mention of the G-dly soul of the Non-jews (Maybe because there is none according to the Alter Rebbe?)

In a lot of sources the non-Jews are associated with Tumah. E.g. Ben Ish Chai on Parashat Balak:

שאם ישראל יהיו צדיקים ושלמים מצד עצמם ודאי אין מי שיעמוד כנגדם ואין אומה שתוכל לעשות כמעשיהם ולהתדמות באחד מאלף להם כי **האומה אשר שורשה רע גם כי תטהר קצת מ"מ עודנה בטומאתה**

On the other Hand the jewish Nation is supposed to be *Or laGoyim* and to teach the world in the ways of G-d.

I find it challenging to be a light to the nations while knowing that they are actually the ambassadors of *Tumah* and I am unsure if this is how Non-jews are seen by Kabbalistic sources.

Is there any source (preferably Kaballah and lurianic Kaballah or Chasidut) which gives a clear statement about what the essence of the non jewish Persons soul actually is.

I am not looking for halachic rulings connected to our attitude towards non-Jews but for the metaphysical essence of the Non-jewish person.

Comment: I think the logical course of action would be to continue reading Tanya itself, with some commentary(s) and shiurim, and try your best to understand its overall teachings. What the Alter Rebbe is trying to convey in what you are referring to is likely to get lost and confused if you switch text or chain of thought until you've made some progress there, just like in any big philosophical work like this.

Comment: Rabbi Manis Friedman states [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPFmsl09zCk&ab_channel=RabbiManisFriedman), on ch1, that the type of soul that has no built-in goodness's service to God is to incorporate external goodness into it and make it good. Light of Torah helps with this.

Comment: This was famously a sticking point for the Russian authorities who interrogated the Alter Rebbe after he was accused of anti-Czarist activities. Reportedly he just smiled, as if to say "it is what it is," and they dropped the matter. See also [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57761/6592) and [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9371/6592).

Comment: While I understand you are primarily seeking Lurianic/Hassidic sources that address this issue, it is worth pointing out that those sources that do not assume an ontic difference between the soul of a Jew and a gentile are not challenged by this conflict.

Comment: חביב אדם שנברא בצלם